# Start console program from AppleScript and monitor it status

Tags: macos, applescript, console-application

I attempted to start console program from AppleScript and restart when it crashes. I wrote this code

```
repeat
     do shell script "/path/to/program"
end repeat
```

But it hangs and mac can`t reboot.
How can i put "do shell script" in another thread?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is put a "&" character at the end of your command. That sends it to the background. However I would not use your code. That repeat loop will run forever and spawn new processes for as long as it runs. Your best bet would be to run a stay-open applescript which periodically checks if the process is running. If it isn't then the applescript could launch it. The repeat loop is not what you want. Try this code. Save it as an application and check the box for stay-open in the save window.

```
on run

end run

on idle
    set runShellScript to false

    tell application "System Events"
        if not (exists process "processName") then
            set runShellScript to true
        end if
    end tell

    if runShellScript then do shell script "/path/to/program &"

    return 30 -- the script will stop for 30 seconds then run again until you quit the applescript
end idle
```